# How Can Resume To Last Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, resume

When I open the app again, my previous activity when I press the Resume button in the Main How do I go on

Main Activity

Note:Buton 500 Resume Button

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionBar =getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_giris);

    button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button500= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button500);


    button500.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Giris.this, Soru1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Quest 1

Comment: Need a bit more context/info

Comment: Can you give elaborate detail?  Share your code.

Comment: I Made Application Quiz Game.If I Close The Application, The Last Known I Want To Continue With The Question.What I want on the MENU button and continue from where it left off

Comment: Still a little confused. Can you explain exactly what is going on and what you want

Comment: Think Of A Game.In The Menu You Have And Resume Button Will Continue From Where You Left Off.I Want To Do Exactly This

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be using Shared Preferences. You can save the name of the last activity you used in a String in Shared Preferences, load it and start the activity which you need. You can look up how to use Shared Preferences here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Also, here is the code example how that can be done:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String activityName = getResources().getString(R.string.saved_activity);
switch (activityName) {
    case "activityA":
        //start activity A
        break;
    case "activityB":
        //start activity B
        break;
}
```